# What happens if you have the terraria old man AND the clothier at the same time?

Tags: terraria

What happens if you have the old man and the clothier at the same time and throw in the clothier voodoo doll? Who will die and will there be 2 skeletrons?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact you can’t have both an Old Man and a Clothier at once, the Voodoo doll doesn’t work the same as the Guide Voodoo doll.

You cannot destroy it with lava. Instead, equipping it allows you to directly damage the Clothier. On his death Skeletron is spawned. The Voodoo doll does not allow you to kill the Old Man, but talking to him with another Skeletron in the world will spawn a second.

This can never happen in normal gameplay though, since there is only ever one of the Old Man or Clothier.